# Using WYIHTML5 when adding a new field with nested_form gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, wysiwyg

I am trying to use [WYSIHTML5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) with Rails nested forms, using the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/) gem.

My initial problem came up when generating a new set of fields through nested_form's `link_to_add` feature. From what I understand, it duplicates a pre-generated field (the "blueprint"). WYSIHTML5 uses iFrames and the iFrame content wasn't being copied over. The `body` was missing a `contenteditable` attribute, so it was pretty much useless. I managed to copy over all the missing attributes with nested_form's `nested:fieldAdded` javascript trigger.

So now everything is editable and looks right. New problem. The `iframe` is apparently not tied to the original `textarea`. I can type whatever I want to, but it doesn't get submitted with the form. I can't figure out what I'm missing here. The `iframe` doesn't have any id attribute or seemingly anything that would tie the two together.

Any help would be appreciated. If I left out any details, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually linking everything together turned out to be too much of a pain.

I basically ended up ignoring the blueprint textarea with `$('.wysiwyg:not([id$="_blueprint"] .wysiwyg)')`. Then on the `nested:fieldAdded` jQuery trigger, I select `$('.wysiwyg-inactive:not([id$="_blueprint"] .wysiwyg)')` and activate them, using `wysiwyg-inactive` and `wysiwyg-active` classes to make sure I don't double activate them

Sort of clean. Sort of simple. But there you have it.